# Real time location tracking delays on updates

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an app for real time gps tracking for a group of users. I managed to display every user location with a marker on the map (map activity - using Google Maps), and also to update the location on the map every 5 seconds (I update the 'longitude' and 'latitude' fields of the user in Firebase Database every 3 seconds, and then read this fields every 5 seconds and update all the markers on the map).

I tried walking around with 3 different phones, and noticed that not all the markers (its not always the same markers, but if some marker is stuck on one phone, the same marker is stuck on the other phones) are moving with me as I walk. They start moving in the beginning for a small amount of time and then they stop moving at all. After I keep walking for a while they suddenly update (jump to the current location) and then stuck again... Or in other words the updates of some of the markers happens with big delays.

What could be the reason for such delays and how can I fix it?

**Pictures of my Firebase Database (Managers and Users):**

[Pictures of my Firebase Database - Managers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ujiJ.png)

[Pictures of my Firebase Database - Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQWoY.png)

(I create a manager which represents a group, and the manager have a list of users that are in his group, and then I go through the list of users of the manager and update their location on Firebase Database. Then when a user click on 'map' button it goes through to GroupMapActivity and there I read the locations from Firebase Databse every 5 seconds and update the markers).

**The code for updating the location on Firebase Database using service:**

```
package com.example.lidor.findmygroup;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class FindMeService extends IntentService
{
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    String userEmail = "", key = "";
    LocationTrack locationTrack;
    double longitude, latitude;
    User user;

    public FindMeService()
    {
        super("FindMeService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        if (intent.hasExtra("email"))
            userEmail = intent.getStringExtra("email").toString();

        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("USERS");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    User curUser = d.getValue(User.class);
                    if (userEmail.equals(curUser.Email))
                    {
                        key = d.getKey();
                        user = curUser;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(3000);

                locationTrack = new LocationTrack(FindMeService.this);
                if (locationTrack.canGetLocation())
                {
                    longitude = locationTrack.getLongitude();
                    latitude = locationTrack.getLatitude();

                    databaseReference.child("USERS").child(key).
                            addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                                {
                                    Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
                                    for (DataSnapshot s : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                                    {
                                        updates.put(s.getKey(), s.getValue());
                                    }
                                    updates.put("UserName", user.UserName);
                                    updates.put("Age", user.Age);
                                    updates.put("Phone", user.Phone);
                                    updates.put("City", user.City);
                                    updates.put("Email", user.Email);
                                    updates.put("longitude", longitude);
                                    updates.put("latitude", latitude);
                                    updates.put("Is_In_Group", user.Is_In_Group);
                                    updates.put("ManagerEmail", user.ManagerEmail);
                                    updates.put("Is_Manager", user.Is_Manager);
                                    updates.put("Is_Connected", user.Is_Connected);

                                    databaseReference.child(key).updateChildren(updates);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                }
                            });
                }
                else
                {
                    locationTrack.showSettingsAlert();
                    Toast.makeText(FindMeService.this, "No GPS signal",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**The Group Map Activity:**

```
package com.example.lidor.findmygroup;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class GroupMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
{
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    Handler handler;
    String email = "", managerEmail = "", managerKey = "";
    int i = 0;
    Marker marker;

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase, firebaseDatabase1, firebaseDatabase2;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference, databaseReference1, databaseReference2;

    Boolean endFor = false, endFor1 = false, endFor2 = false;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    HashMap<String, Marker> markers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_group_map);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        firebaseDatabase1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        firebaseDatabase2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        //builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.hasExtra("email")) email = intent.getStringExtra("email").toString();
        markers = new HashMap<>();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(GroupMapActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Map Loading Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        mMap = googleMap;

        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Real_Time_Group_Map();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    public void Real_Time_Group_Map()
    {
        // 1# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("USERS");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    if (endFor) continue;

                    User curUser = d.getValue(User.class);
                    if (email.equals(curUser.Email))
                    {
                        endFor = true;
                        managerEmail = curUser.ManagerEmail;

                        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("MANAGERS");
                        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                            {
                                for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                                {
                                    if (endFor1) continue;

                                    Manager curManager = d.getValue(Manager.class);
                                    if (managerEmail.equals(curManager.Email))
                                    {
                                        endFor1 = true;
                                        managerKey = d.getKey();

                                        databaseReference1 = firebaseDatabase1.getReference("MANAGERS").
                                                child(managerKey).child("Group Users");
                                        databaseReference1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
                                        {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                                            {

                                                for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                                                {
                                                    final String curFriend = d.getValue().toString();

                                                    databaseReference2 = firebaseDatabase2.getReference("USERS");
                                                    databaseReference2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
                                                    {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                                                        {
                                                            for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                                                            {
                                                                User curUser = d.getValue(User.class);
                                                                String emailUser = curUser.Email;

                                                                if (curFriend.equals(emailUser))
                                                                {
                                                                    LatLng location = new LatLng(
                                                                            curUser.latitude, curUser.longitude);

                                                                    Marker delMarker = markers.get(emailUser);
                                                                    if (delMarker != null) delMarker.remove();
                                                                    markers.remove(emailUser);

                                                                    if (curUser.Is_Manager)
                                                                    {
                                                                        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                                                                      .position(location).title(curUser.UserName).icon(
                                                                                       BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(
                                                                                       BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)).
                                                                                       snippet(emailUser));
                                                                    }

                                                                    else
                                                                    {
                                                                        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                                                                     .position(location).title(curUser.UserName)
                                                                                     .snippet(emailUser));

                                                                    }

                                                                    markers.put(emailUser, marker);
                                                                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location,18));
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }

                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                }

                                                mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener()
                                                {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker)
                                                    {
                                                        Intent intent = new Intent(GroupMapActivity.this, MemberActivity.class);
                                                        intent.putExtra("email", marker.getSnippet());
                                                        startActivity(intent);
                                                        return false;
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                            }
                                        });

                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            }
                        });

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Firebase is a realtime database--there is no need to actively request data from the server. Uploading the new coordinates from the device is enough to trigger updated positions (using `onDataChange`) on each device. Even the uploading of the coordinates need not be "every 3 sec."  just allow the location manager to register updated positions.

Comment: You shared over 350 lines of code. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Since Stack Overflow is not a good interactive debugger: isolate the problem in a small piece of code. It's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AlexMamo How can I edit my question? Couldn't find it.

Comment: @tehilooli Under the question and tags, there is an edit button, see?